# How can I sort 1 million numbers, and only print the top 10 in Python?

Tags: python

I have a file that has 1 million numbers. I need to know how I can sort it efficiently, so that it doesn't stall the computer, and it prints ONLY the top 10.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#Find the 10 largest integers
#Don't store the whole list

import sys

def fOpen(fname):
        try:
                fd = open(fname,"r")
        except:
                print("Couldn't open file.")
                sys.exit(0)
        all = fd.read().splitlines()
        fd.close()
        return all

words = fOpen(sys.argv[1])

big = 0
g = len(words)
count = 10

for i in range(0,g-1):
        pos = i
        for j in range(i+1,g):
                if words[j] > words[pos]:
                        pos = j
                if pos != i:
                        words[i],words[pos] = words[pos],words[i]
                count -= 1
                if count == 0:
                        print(words[0:10])
```

I know that this is selection sort, I'm not sure what would be the best sort to do.

Comment: Is this homework? Or an exercise from a book?

Comment: This is obviously a [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341). The problem is not sorting, but finding the ten largest integers. While they can be found by first sorting and then picking the top ten entries, this is not the best solution. The best solution is the one provided by _pepsi_.

Comment: I wouldn't say pepsi solution is the "best possible", perhaps the first incumbent solution. In fact he didn't actually provide any working code but did show it was an XY problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you only need the top 10 values, then you'd waste a lot of time sorting every single number.

Just go through the list of numbers and keep track of the top 10 largest values seen so far. Update the top ten as you go through the list, and print them out when you reach the end.

This will mean you only need to make a single pass through the file (ie time complexity of theta(n))

**A simpler problem**

You can look at your problem as a generalization of finding the maximum value in a list of numbers. If you're given `{2,32,33,55,13, ...}` and are asked to find the largest value, what would you do? The typical solution is to go through the list, while remembering the largest number encountered so far and comparing it with the next number.

For simplicity, let's assume we're dealing with positive numbers.

```
Initialize max to 0
0 < 2, so max = 2
2 < 32, so max = 32
32 < 33, so max = 33
33 < 55, so max = 55
55 > 13, so max = 55
...
return max
```

So you see, we can find the max in a single traversal of the list, as opposed to any kind of comparison sort.

**Generalizing**

Finding the **top 10** values in a list is very similar. The only difference is that we need to keep track of the top 10 instead of just the max (top 1).

The bottom line is that you need some container that holds 10 values. As you're iterating through your giant list of numbers, the only value you care about in your size-10-container is the minimum. That's because this is the number that would be replaced if you've discovered a new number that deserves to be in the top-10-so-far.

Anyway it turns out that the data structure best fit for finding mins quickly is a min heap. But I'm not sure if you've learned about heaps yet, and the overhead of using a heap for 10 elements could possibly outweigh its benefits.

Any container that holds 10 elements and can obtain the min in a reasonable amount of time would be a good start.

Comment: This does risk being 10x slower which may mean 10 milliseconds instead of 1 millisecond. but it could mean 10 seconds instead of 1 second.

Comment: if you want to the top K values, then this is O(KN) (depending on how you keep track of the top 10), check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm, something such as median of medians is O(N)

Comment: @robertking : In the OP's problem, k is given as a constant 10, which is why I simplified it to theta(n). If we actually care about a generic algorithm for the top k values, we can use a heap of size k to track the top k values, reducing it to theta(n*lg(k)). This is likely what heapq does as well. But who knows, maybe the overhead of managing a heap is greater than the overhead of traversing a size 10 array. You'd have to profile it to find out.

Comment: True. I like how your answer shows that one need not sort the entire list. However "just track the top 10 largest values" isn't as easy as it looks in my opinion. more simply one could just take the minimum of the list and then pop the minimum. do this ten times and it may be as fast.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still learning algorithms and such for CS. Care for a brief explain on what I should do to run the list of 10 over the 1 million numbers?

Comment: @pepsi: The heap solution is not optimal either.  Selection is O(n) irrespective of k.

Comment: @NeilG see my answer for a selection method.

Comment: @NeilG : This is true, but remember we're dealing with numbers in a large file, and the OP's code has a comment that says "Don't store the whole list". The method given here does a single pass through the file, which means the entire file does not need to be read into memory at once. In addition, the file is read sequentially, which takes advantage of the fact that sequential disk IO is much faster than random. This is important, given that the IO is likely to be the bottleneck.

Comment: @pepsi: Good point on noticing the comment that says not to store the whole (although a million numbers isn't really a "large file").  You're right that your solution does a single sequential pass.  However, "quickselect" will also access the file sequentially rather randomly (but it usually needs many passes).

Answer (score 26):

The best sort is a partial sort, available in the Python library as [`heapq.nlargest`](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest).

Comment: this way you have a beautiful O(n) solution instead a O(nlogn)

Comment: @julio.alegria: and O(1) memory.

Comment: Best thing about this: you can supply a key function, just like with `sorted`.

Answer (score 14):

```
import heapq

with open('nums.txt') as f:
    numbers=map(int,f.readlines())
    print heapq.nlargest(10,numbers)
    print heapq.nsmallest(10,numbers)
"""
[1132513251, 13252365, 23512, 2000, 1251, 1235, 324, 100, 82, 82]
[1, 1, 7, 13, 15, 21, 22, 22, 33, 82]
"""
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, this is the solution I went with.
With 1 million words, it takes only about 4 seconds. Thanks you!

Comment: Hmm I would have thought it would be faster than that. Perhaps your IO is slower than mine. Anyway readlines() should be the fastest way to read the lines, which is probably the bottleneck here. Feel free to upvote the other solutions or give the green tick

Comment: @SethRainerKania just letting you know, a python inbuilt solution is probably not the one your teacher is looking for, and might not get you any points.

Comment: I'll take that into consideration. At least while I work on a new answer, I have the correct top 10.

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm Note also the difference between O(N) and O(KN)

Comment: The prefered way to create the list of numbers would be `numbers = map(int, f)`.  This avoids storing the whole file contents in memory (and saves some typing, too).

Comment: Thanks Sven. That would be my preferred  way, especially if the file was larger.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a good [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)

The following python code is based around the function  `partition()`
partition splits the list into two. Values less than "pivotValue" are moved to the start of the list. Values greater than pivotValue are moved to the end of the list.
This is done in O(N) operations by going through the list from start to end, each time it looks at a value it moves it near the start of the list, only if it is smaller than the pivot value.

(note in your case we actually move the larger values to the start of the list since you want the biggest values not the smallest).

Once we have partitioned the list in O(N) time, we are left with m large numbers at the start of the list. if m=10 then great, thats your ten biggest numbers. if m is bigger than 10, then we need to partition the m biggest numbers again to get the 10 biggest numbers from the m biggest numbers. if m is smaller than 10 then we need 10-m more numbers, so we partition the righter partion to find the 10-m numbers and add them to our m numbers to get the 10 numbers we needed.

So we keep partitioning until we have 10 largest numbers. This is done by the `select()` method. The whole method is usually very quick because each time we do a partition we are left with about half as many numbers to deal with. (if you constantly divide the number of numbers you need to look at by two, that's good). Each time we do a partition that yields more than 10 larger numbers, we get to ignore a whole heap of numbers that are too small.

Here is the code:

```
def partition(_list,left,right,pivotIndex):
    pivotValue=_list[pivotIndex]
    _list[right],_list[pivotIndex]=pivotValue,_list[right]
    storeIndex=left
    for i in range(left,right):
        if _list[i] > pivotValue:
            _list[storeIndex],_list[i]=_list[i],_list[storeIndex]
            storeIndex+=1
    _list[right],_list[storeIndex]=_list[storeIndex],_list[right]
    return storeIndex

from random import randint
def select(_list,left,right,k):
    if left==right:
        return _list[:left+1]
    pivotIndex=randint(left,right)
    pivotNewIndex=partition(_list,left,right,pivotIndex)
    pivotDist=pivotNewIndex-left+1
    if pivotDist==k:
        return _list[:pivotNewIndex+1]
    elif k<pivotDist:
        return select(_list,left,pivotNewIndex-1,k)
    else:
        return select(_list,pivotNewIndex+1,right,k-pivotDist)

_list=[1,2,109,2234,23,6,1,234,11,4,12451,1]

left=0
right=len(_list)-1
pivotIndex=4

print _list
"[1, 2, 109, 2234, 23, 6, 1, 234, 11, 4, 12451, 1]"
print partition(_list,left,right,pivotIndex) #partition is order(N).
"7" #index 7, so the lowest number are in the first 7 numbers of the list [1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 11, 4, 23]
print _list
"[1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 11, 4, 23, 2234, 109, 12451, 234]"
print select(_list,left,right,10)
"[1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 11, 6, 23, 109, 234]"

with open('nums.txt') as f:
    numbers=map(int,f.readlines())
    print select(numbers,0,len(numbers)-1,10)
    "[1132513251, 2000, 23512, 13252365, 1235, 1251, 324, 100, 82, 82]"
```

Comment: Nice.  Although, you probably should be returning slices rather than copying lists, and your code would be easier to read if you followed [pep 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)