# Finding the largest K numbers in an unsorted array

Tags: java, algorithm, partition, quickselect

I am trying to find the largest K numbers given a sorted array.

ex:
input - > [ 5, 12, 45, 32, 9, 20, 15]
output -> K = 3, [45, 32, 20]

The code that I have written so far returns the largest K element, but it needs to return the largest K numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static int max_Numbers(int [] p, int K, int firstNum, int lastNum)
    {
        int pivot = partitionArr(p, firstNum, lastNum);
        int m = p.length - K;
        if (m == pivot)
        {
            return p[pivot];
        }
        if(m > pivot)
        {
            return max_Numbers(p, K, pivot + 1, lastNum);

        }
        else
        {
            return max_Numbers(p, K, firstNum, pivot - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If efficiency isn't important just sort it and return to the top k

Comment: The average running time should be O(n)

Comment: Is O(n log k) also acceptable?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227698/write-a-program-to-find-100-largest-numbers-out-of-an-array-of-1-billion-numbers.

Comment: The problem I am working on asks that it should be O(n).

Comment: Also, note that your question could be closed as "Too broad" (since it is a "please help me" rather than a proper question) and "Off topic" (since it is apparently a request for debugging assistance without a proper MCVE)

Comment: There is no `O(N)` solution.  There is an `O(NlogK)` solution.  Check that you have understood the problem.  (Hint: if you substitute a specific value for `K`, that makes this a problem with an `O(N)` solution.)

Comment: @stephenC: nowhere does it say the numbers need to be returned in order, although you may be right that it is somehow implicit.

Comment: @rici - The Question I linked to doesn't specify that the K elements should be delivered in order.   I don't think I mentioned ordering ...

Comment: @user11082882 - If you want a well-written explanation, read https://www.baeldung.com/java-kth-largest-element

Comment: @stephenc: i didn't look at the question you linked to but an O(n) solution to the partitioning problem is [well-known](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians). But it is only linear if you don't need the partition to be sorted (or, as you say, k is considered to be constant.)

Comment: (QuickSelect with median-of-medians partitioning is not efficient in practice. But it is guaranteed O(n).)

Comment: @rici how do you decide the pivot to use that algorithm?

Comment: @msk: as described in the linked wikipedia article, you compute the median of medians, which gives you a guaranteed non-pathological pivot. You can compute the median of medians in O(n).

Comment: If the array is already sorted, you return the sub-array starting at index `N-K`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Using your sorted array,

```
for(int i=array.length-1; i>=0 && array.length-1 - i < K; i--) System.out.println(array[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

One property of the pivot and partition you are using is that after every partition step, it is guaranteed that all elements before the pivot happen to be smaller or equal than the pivot, and everything after the pivot is larger. Thus, after you find the pivot that is the K-th, the array will have the K largest after it.