# Sorting points on multiple lines

Tags: python, math

Given that we have two lines on a graph (I just noticed that I inverted the numbers on the Y axis, this was a mistake, it should go from 11-1)

[image: Two lines on a graph]

And we only care about whole number X axis intersections

[image: Two lines on a graph with intersections]

We need to order these points from highest Y value to lowest Y value regardless of their position on the X axis (Note I did these pictures by hand so they may not line up perfectly).

[image: Two lines on a graph with intersections and ordering]

I have a couple of questions:

1) I have to assume this is a known problem, but does it have a particular name?

2) Is there a known optimal solution when dealing with tens of billions (or hundreds of millions) of lines? Our current process of manually calculating each point and then comparing it to a giant list requires *hours* of processing. Even though we may have a hundred million lines we typically only want the top 100 or 50,000 results some of them are so far "below" other lines that calculating their points is unnecessary.

Comment: I am not sure of the solution but I wouldnt use python to deal with "tens of billions" of any stuff since it will be slow at that point, I would use C

Comment: @lapinkoira Do you have any proof for that?

Comment: What are the limits on X and Y coordinates?

Comment: @johndoevodka there are no limits, but all lines trend in from high-to-low, does that make sense?

Comment: @samwise gamgee: The no limits part doesn't make sense actually; imagine you sampled the two lines around X=-100 -- you'd get vastly different Y coordinate values there than the ones above. X=-1000 -- even crazier. In fact, there's no upper bound on the Y values (which means you can't order them or get a list of the highest Y values). Did you mean to limit your problem only for values with X >= 0?

Comment: you are correct, my apologies, all lines start at X=1 and trend till Y=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your data structure is a `set` of tuples

   ```
   lines = {(y0, Δy0), (y1, Δy1), ...}
   ```
2. You need only the `ntop` points, hence build a `set` containing only
   the top `ntop` `yi` values, with a single pass over the data

   ```
   top_points = choose(lines, ntop)
   ```

   EDIT --- to choose the `ntop` we had to keep track of the smallest
   one, and this is interesting info, so let's return also this value
   from `choose`, also we need to initialize `decremented`

   ```
   top_points, smallest = choose(lines, ntop)
   decremented = top_points
   ```

   and start a loop...

   ```
   while True:
   ```
3. Generate a `set` of decremented values

   <strike>decremented = {(y-Δy, Δy) for y, Δy in top_points}</strike>

   ```
       decremented = {(y-Δy, Δy) for y, Δy in decremented if y>smallest}
       if decremented == {}: break
   ```
4. Generate a set of candidates

   ```
       candidates = top_lines.union(decremented)
   ```
5. generate a new set of top points

   ```
       new_top_points, smallest = choose(candidates, ntop)
   ```

   The following is no more necessary
6. check if `new_top_points == top_points`

   ```
       if new_top_points == top_points: break
       top_points = new_top_points</strike>
   ```

   of course we are in a loop...

The difficult part is the `choose` function, but I think that [this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9236436/2749397) to the question
[How can I sort 1 million numbers, and only print the top 10 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236387/how-can-i-sort-1-million-numbers-and-only-print-the-top-10-in-python)
could help you.

Comment: Thinking about it, there are a number of possible optimisations, e.g. using `numpy`, or reducing the size of `decremented` at each step removing all the items smaller than the smallest element in `top_points` before the `union()`... but this is premature optimisation, isn't it?

Comment: I edited my answer to incorporate the second optimisation I talked about in my previous comment, because thinking a bit about it it is so simple that it seems necessary...

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not a really complicated thing, just a "normal" sorting problem.
2. Usually sorting requires a large amount of computing time. But your case is one where you don't need to use complex sorting techniques.

You on both graphs are growing or falling constantly, there are no "jumps". You can use this to your advantage. The basic algorithm:

- identify if a graph is growing or falling.
- write a generator, that generates the values; from left to right if raising, form right to left if falling.
- get the first value from both graphs
- insert the lower on into the result list
- get a new value from the graph that had the lower value
- repeat the last two steps until one generator is "empty"
- append the leftover items from the other generator.

Comment: Thank you, we currently do what you describe which is why I'm looking for more information (like a name or a paper), the problem is when you get to the first couple hundred million lines all these generators fall apart. I don't really need code, just a description of potential solutions beyond manually calculating each point in the line

Comment: The generators should be able to handle very long rows. I would see problem with the results. The result list would grow rapidly, increasing the memory consumption. So you might want to store it to disk after some time. Maybe a million values. But in general it's a O(n) algorithm, you won't get anything faster for sorting. If there is a bottle neck it's implementation specific. Something like memory consumption or I/O.